# Login Error using facebook-swift-sdk in ios

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

Im getting a login error every time I try to login to my application using the facebook sdk. So when the user gets to the home page they can choose to login with their facebook credentials. When they hit the facebook login button it brings up the user name and password screen, which they then type in their credentials and press done. Now here's the issue, well since it wasn't happening before, when they hit done facebook returns an error stating **"LOGIN FAILED: You can't use facebook to log into this app or website because there's an issue with its implementation of Facebook login"**. I get this every time I try and login using the facebook sdk.

Im using FBSDKCoreKit, FBSDKLoginKit, FBSDKShareKit 4.41.0 and FacebookCore, FacebookLogin, FacebookShare 0.5.0 and Swift 4.0

EDIT ***.
Does anyone know how I can find the error being returned from the facebook login request. The issue is this error message that is showing is appearing in the facebook application before it returns to my application. SO I cant even see the error that is being returned. I checked the response in Xcode when the debugger continued and there is no error

EDIT 2:(In response to the first comment)
  The application was already set up to use the facebook sdk and it was working fine. It just recently stopped working.

EDIT 3:
So I Ended up having to update the sdk to the newest versiom and replace the old apis with the new apis they created. So I changed everything out and here comes another problem. I try and login with an account I just created on facebook and it still gives me the same error. Yet, if I try and login with an account that has been previously logged into the application using facebook. I get a successful response and im able to continue on with the application. So I dont get why that new account isn't able to login? Is it because the account is too new?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I'm trying to fix this same issue in an app that apparently has everything setup correctly but it keeps throwing this error. I wonder if we need to send the app for revision to FB again.

Comment: That's the issue with me I'm not even getting an error. I get to the facebook login view, put in the credentials and when I press login it says 'there's something wrong with the implementation" and doesnt throw me an error. I believe it's because the application is still in swift 4.0 I'm migrating everything to swift 4.3. Don't think I need swift 5.0 for this. Since I'm still doing that I need to complete the migration first before I can test the facebook login again.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in my app. It happend also if you remove the permission of the app from your facebook account.

Comment: Why version of swift are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I AM getting the same error as you. Facebook login has been working since the app was created. Now when I try and login after updating the Facebook SDK, I get no error only "Something is wrong with the implementation" what's weird is if someone has already logged in through facebook the facebook login works correctly.

Answer (score -3):

This is because you haven't set up your app. go to https://developers.facebook.com -> My Apps -> add your app then follow the steps for login.

That should resolve it!

Comment: What do you mean? This app was already set up and able to login using the facebook sdk. It just recently broke.